# Is there a way using pulseaudio to direct Skype Speakers and Ringing to different devices?

Tags: skype, pulseaudio

I just upgraded from CentOS 5.5 to 6.3, which uses pulseaudio for sound.

When using CentOS 5.5, all my sound devices showed up for each Sound option, so I could select my desktop speakers for Ringing and Headset for Speakers (their term for listening during a conversation).

Under CentOS 6.3, only Pulseaudio shows up for the sound options, so all options (Speaker, Microphone, Ringing) are set to the headset. As a result, since I don't wear my headset all the time, I don't hear ringing.

Is there a way to configure Skype under CentOS 6.3 so I can get Ringing to go to the desktop speakers and Speakers (listening during a conversation) to go to the headset?

Thanks,
-W.

Answer (score 0):

Most recent version of Skype mark the ringing and call streams differently, so PulseAudio can distinguish between the two. Streams can take a 'media.role' property. Ringing sounds are marked with the 'event' role, and call streams are marked with the 'phone' role.

PulseAudio tries to autodetect what kind of role the hardware you have is intended for. It can't do much with built-in cards, but stuff like USB and Bluetooth headsets get an "intended role" of 'phone'. So streams with the 'phone' role are routed to such devices.

This means that if your headset has the 'phone' intended role (look for device.intended_roles in the output of 'pactl list sinks'), then your call streams will automatically use that device.

If not, you can use another PulseAudio behaviour for this. During a call, move the call streams to the device you want (both the playback and capture streams). You will need the pavucontrol app to do this (can be done on the command line too). Once you move them, *all* phone streams will be routed to that device by default if the device is available (PulseAudio tries to remember these explicit routing decisions that you make when you move the stream).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I still cannot get this to work. None of my sound devices has media.role 'event', so there doesn't seem to be a way to get ringing to go someplace special. This is true whether I plug my speakers into the internal sound device or whether I plug them into a USB sound card. Maybe the question boils down to: How can I give either of these sound devices the media.role 'event'?  

I can use the Playback tab of pavucontrol to redirect the audio streams, but, as you stated, both output streams (ringing and listening) get sent to the same device.

Comment: This would all "just work" if your desktop sink the default. I'm guessing it is not. This isn't really the cleanest solution, but one thing you can do to move the event output (note that _all_ event sounds will get routed to your speakers, not just Skype). In a console, run 'PULSE_PROP="media.role=event" paplay --raw /dev/zero'. You should now see a paplay stream in pavucontrol. Moving this to speakers should get all event streams routed there. You'll need to go back to the console and 'Ctrl-C' to stop paplay.

Comment: I'm running the most recent version of Skype (4.3.0.37 at this time). Using `pacmd` and `list-sink-inputs` while Skype is ringing, and while Skype is in a voice call, I can see that it is always using "media.roll = phone". So it seems that with this current version of Skype, there is no way for pulseaudio to distinguish between the ringing sound and the voice conversation.

Comment: It's possible they broke this again. I'll try to take a look and ping the Skype team. It would also be interesting to see if the new Skype client does things better. Not entirely hopeful since it's just a webapp, and I don't think there's API to mark stream metadata in WebAudio, and if that would be properly translated to native stream types.